# Diode for overvoltage

Tags: diodes, pic, over-voltage-protection

This may appear as a very simple question but I am looking for a cross reference for the BAT 54 diode. Here were I live, I can't get that diode. The circuit that I am using is below, so you have an idea what I am using it for. It is basically for connecting a battery to an ADC converter.  If the battery exceeds the 5V input maximum voltage, the diode protects the pic.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but the diode won't protect the PIC because the 7805 won't stop voltages rising above 5 volts on its output (due to current through the diode).

Comment: @Andyaka So how i can protect the pic from connecting something above 5v?

Comment: Something above 5 volts might be 100,000 volts so, to start with, you need to be realistic about what might happen. If it's (say) 10 volts then R1 will limit the current to a value of 0.5 mA and this could  be acceptable if you read the data sheet for the PIC. Now, a diode isn't needed but, you have to make a decision about that voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka . I calculate the max voltage input, its something about 23v, it would be like an amp in the input

Comment: Use a voltage divider then diode clamp that. Any Schotky diode should be sufficient.

Comment: There's a 10k in the input so, the most it can be (input raised to 5.3 volts) is 1.77 mA. Probably too much for the input so, maybe increase the resistor.

Comment: @Andyaka and a bleed resistor across the rail if necessary since the LM7805 can't sink current from the cap to reduce the rail voltage. Wastes power but is simple.

Comment: Possibly a 5.1 volt zener diode will do the job @DKNguyen

Comment: @Andyaka That would do it too if OP can get one. And works when battery is connected but power is off. Rail clamp steering diodes do nothing with no rail power.

Comment: @Andyaka Ok! I know that im asking to much, but you can make a diagram of the circuit? because i know how to talk english but i dont know what the name of the circuits that you are saying means.

Comment: Make R1 bigger so that the current through it is below the limit defined in the data sheet for the PIC.

Comment: @DKNguyen i cant use a voltage divider, because im already using one, the maximum voltage that i calculate its the output of the voltage divider. And if the bleed resistor is for electric shock, im not worried about that because its isolated and inside of a box

Comment: @Andyaka the 10k resistor its because, when i connected the battery first, the pic tries to power up from the AN2 input, so i have to put that for not latching up. If i make R1 bigger it wouldnt be a problem?

Comment: Less of a problem.

Comment: @Andyaka how much bigger it has to be if the maximum input its 24v? with 20K it would be 1mA, and in the datasheet of the pic16f684 i dont find the max input current, i assume thats because the input is in high impedance state

Comment: page 127 of the data sheet however, with this amount of current it will be too high so go for an R1 value that limits current to less than 0.5 mA is my advice.